# Nested Interafce in java

Tags: java

This is my java code:

```
class A {
    interface That {
        void show();
    }
}

class B implements A.That {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.That object = new B();
        object.show();
    }
}
```

Since A is a class (not abstract) we can create its instance and than we can use members of that instance. Now interface is member so `obj.That` should work but javac says that `obj.That` is not package. Why?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the full error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java inner class and static nested class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces are always static when nested in a class. You should therefore access your interface declaration as `A.That`, not `obj.That`.

Comment: But we can access static member using instance,so why cannot interface?

Comment: If `That` was a class rather than an interface, you couldn't say `obj.That` either. You should always refer to the type as `A.That`, no matter whether it's an interface or a class, or an enum, or whatnot.

Comment: "Compilable" != "preferable". Do not refer to static members through an instance. You don't need to instantiate an `A` instance here.